# Login with paypal using paypal ios sdk

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a requirement where a user can sell an item from his iOS app and another user can purchase it. So at the time of selling he need to login to PayPal using his credentials. I should be able know wether this user is a valid user.
Initially i tried out this workflow using Paypal's identity api and log in with paypal api. My reference can be found [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox).

I need to get this workflow done using PayPal's iOS SDK. I could find sample code and documentation on payment, future payment etc. But what i need is that:
1. the user logs in to paypal
2. Once login is successful, the app receives a response which will give the user's paypal email id and isVerified status.

It would be very helpful if any one could advice me on how to achieve this work flow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

At the moment, this is not a workflow that the PayPal iOS SDK can help you with, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you @Dave for your response. So I think i shall better go with the available PayPal apis (ie, Commerce identity solution) to achieve my desire work flow.